# E3004: This package is for device: gts210vewifi; this device is

Tags: lineageos, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-10.1

I'm trying upgrade a [Samsung Galaxy Tab S2 9.7 Wi-Fi (2016) AKA gts210vewifi](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/gts210vewifi) from a LineageOS 18 April 2017 to a 30 July 2018 build, but it fails printing this in TWRP:

```
E3004: This package is for device: gts210vewifi; this device is .
```

What does this apparently broken error message mean? -- Someone suggested that perhaps I "need to upgrade the firmware".. how would I need which version this new build requires?

Answer (score 8):

OK, so this means that you have an outdated version of TWRP which, apparently, does not correctly report the device model name (it's empty).  -- 
Updating TWRP from 3.1.0-0 to latest is 3.2.2-0 solved this problem!