# How can I factory-restore a Samsung J5 (2015) SM-500FN?

Tags: samsung, twrp, lineageos, stock-rom, samsung-galaxy-j5

#### What I have:

I have a Samsung J5 (2015) SM-500FN which ran out of storage and basically hung itself up. There is no data I want to recover, but I want to install either a stock ROM or (preferably) something else like Lineage - I just want to get a usable phone again.

#### My problem:

1. I have tried to download *many* stock ROMs from reputable sources like SamMobile ([for this specific phone](https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/galaxy-j5/SM-J500FN/MAX/download/J500FNXXU1BRL1/256333/), but trying different release dates and country codes) but every single one of those ZIPs is corrupt, even when downloading from a different computer.
2. Flashing with ODIN anyway gives a FAIL result and a device that cannot boot, not even into recovery: It gives a green screen with the text: `An error has occurred while updating the device software. Use the Emergency recovery function in the Smart Switch PC software.`
3. Ironically, the Smart Switch software just says this device is not supported. The older Kies3 software lets me enter the exact model# followed by the serial# - but then it says this device is not supported. So neither Samsung software is usable, but I can still use ODIN.
4. Even with the phone in this broken state, I can install TWRP again. So it is not completely bricked. I boot into TWRP and copy a LineageOS ZIP file to /sdcard, but when I try to install that, the TRWP console says: `E3004: This package is for device j5nlte,j5nltexx; this device is .` Note it doesn't appear to recognize that this device is indeed the model j5nlte!
5. Android.SE [says](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/199819/16606) that "E3004" means my TWRP is too old, but I use `twrp-3.1.1-1-j5nlte` which is [currently the newest version](https://eu.dl.twrp.me/j5nlte/) for this phone.
6. I would also like to try a factory reset, but that requires the stock recovery which won't boot (see step 2 above).

#### My question:  How do I get out of this catch-22?

It seems that if I could just get around that E3004 then I would be fine. But I have found no ways to trick the installer into ignoring that error.

Answer (score 0):

A friendly [forum user](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=79246451&postcount=2) pointed me to [this updated version of TWRP](https://android.jenslody.de/BootleggersROM/j5nlte/TWRP/TWRP_3.2.3_j5nlte_20181222_jenslody.img) which I could install using the already installed TWRP.

After upgrading the TWRP itself, I was then able to install the ROM I wanted. Problem solved!