# E3004: This package is for device: gprimeltexx,fortunafz,grandprimelte,grandprimeltexx; this device is

Tags: samsung, rom-flashing, lineageos

I am trying to flash [LineageOS 18.1 GO](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/rom-11-lineageos-18-1-go-for-galaxy-grand-prime.4246293/) custom ROM on my Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime. The model is gprimeltexx, and TWRP works. When I try to flash the ROM, it gives me this error:

```
E3004: This package is for device: gprimeltexx,fortunafz,grandprimelte,grandprimeltexx; this device is .
```

So it says that it is for my model, but it says "This device is ." So it doesn't report any model. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Possible dupe: [E3004: This package is for device: gts210vewifi; this device is](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/199818/44325), looks like it's related to outdated TWRP? Which TWRP version did you flash?

Comment: modify the installer and comment out the line, or set property on cmd line

Comment: The latest version available on twrp.me, so its this version https://twrp.me/samsung/gprimeltexx.html

Comment: And what should I edit in the installer?

Comment: And how do I set "property" in command line?

Comment: how about TWRP provided in your link? https://msm8916.com/?view=downloads&tag=TWRP-3.2.3-lineage-15.1_j8_20180921_gprimeltexx

Comment: in TWRP terminal type *'setprop ro.product.device gprimeltexx'* or delete the line with E3004 error message from *lineage-18.1-20220120-UNOFFICIAL-gprimeltexx-V6stable.zip/META-INF/com/google/android/updater-script* file with Notepad++

Comment: Looks like alecxs's comment solved this, which is great to know! However, that made me wonder why the build prop missing this value. Did you perhaps alter it before?

Answer (score 3):

> in TWRP terminal type 'setprop ro.product.device gprimeltexx'

This fixed my issue. Now all the roms I tried to flash now see my Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime as gprimeltexx.

Thanks everyone for help

Comment: In my case this did not fix it, the property was already set, and problem also remained.
For me (device a3ulte) a fix was to update the TWRP from 3.0.2-1-ashyx to 3.3.1-1.ashyx

Comment: the proper way would be to use `getprop ro.product.device` and see if it reports something. if so, update the recovery and double check if you've got the correct ROM. **--** if it reports nothing (and you are sure about the device name - perhaps `getprop ro.bootloader` can give a hint), use the mentioned command to set it.

Comment: Thank you! I accidentally deleted /system/Build.prop and struggled for too long trying to fix the problem. You are a lifesaver