# ADB sideload lineageOS Samsung J530F: E3004 This package is for device: j5y17ltexx; this device is

Tags: lineageos, side-loading, samsung-galaxy-j5

### Context

While trying to sideload  [this LineageOS](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/rom-10-arm64-lineageos-17-1-for-the-galaxy-j5-pro-j530-02-02-2021.4227945/) from [this link](https://androidfilehost.com/?fid=17248734326145727245), on a Samsung J530F I'm getting the error:

> E3004 This package is for device: j5y17ltexx; this device is .

Normally that message can be used to indicate you are trying to install the wrong/an incompatible operating system on the phone. However, in this case the `this device is .` does not show what the device type actually is. And when I rebooted the phone into its original recovery mode, it said on top:

```
Phone type is:
j5y171texx/j5y171te.
```

So I think the lineageOS package is the right one for the right phone.

### Image with Error:

[image]

### TWRP version

TWRP version is: `3.1.1-0` from the Team Win Recovery Project

### Question

Why does the phone not indicate what type it is/how can I ensure the lineageOS file is installed anyways?

Comment: Possible dupe: [E3004: This package is for device: gprimeltexx,fortunafz,grandprimelte,grandprimeltexx; this device is](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/246959/44325) (missing entry in `build.prop`), [E3004: This package is for device: gts210vewifi; this device is](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/199818/44325) (outdated TWRP)

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to update the twrp version to version 3.2.x. I tried roughly 14 TWRP versions until I found a working one. Additionally on that one I installed TWRP 3.2.x from TWRP 3.1.1-0 (which was installed on the RECOVERY partition), onto the BOOT partition.

Within that new TWRP, the error on installing the Lineagos zip changed from the above to error 7, which also implies the image and the phone are not compatible. One could overrule that by unpacking the image, [taking out some asserts](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/fix-solved-status-7-error-with-cwm-or-twrp-recovery-on-rooted-android.2522762/), and repacking it. However, I did not do that, instead I found an /e/ os image in [this link](https://techn3d.blogspot.com/2021/03/install-e-os-on-samsung-galaxy-j5-pro.html) which did work.